# Scale Background only in width

Tags: html, css

i want my background to scale in width but not in height.

i got following code now.

```
background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

with this code the backgroundimage scales the whole thing but i only want it to scale in width. Does someone have a solution?

greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `cover`, you can try something like this.

```
background-size: 100% $IMAGE_HEIGHT;
```

Where `$IMAGE_HEIGHT` is the height of the background you are working with.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4WS4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to use the background-size property and set/stretch the width, or if it works in your case, try the background-repeat property with value repeat-x:

```
{
    background-size: 100% auto; # width and height, can be %, px or whatever.
}

{
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: same thing, i dont want do repeat it, i want to scale it in but just in one direction.